# How to exclude IPs from VPN routing?

Tags: kubuntu, vpn

I want to prevent certain IP connections to go through my default VPN.
Is that possible at all to set a specific IP or range that should go the normal way, instead of going through a connected VPN?

`ifconfig` shows a `wlp147s0` and a `vpn0`. I'm not having 2 ethernet cards.
How can I now prevent some ips from going through `vpn0`?

Comment: Probably Yes. Read `man ip ip-route`.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked to route the range of `192.0.64.0/18` (simplenote.com) through my local router, instead of the vpn0:

`sudo ip route add 192.0.64.0/18 via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp147s0`